# Ploting images in different windows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot 2 images. When I plot first image, I can see that in figure1. But as I plot another image it is again displayed in the same window figure1.

What I want is to plot 2 different images in two different window. Please don't suggest me to use subplot or hold on, becuase my requirement are different than those.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple.

Everytime you plot a figure, type this:

```
figure;
plot(something);
```